# One way function existence

Tags: terminology, one-way-function, notation

Let $x = (x_1, x_2,...,x_n)\in\{0,1\}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that if one-way functions (OWFs) exist, then there exists a one-way function $f$ such that for every bit $i\in[1,n]$ there exists an algorithm $A_i$ such that:

$$\Pr[A_i(f(x)) = x_i] \geq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$$

I'm having trouble understanding this.

Comment: Note that verbatim questions are considered off topic, please indicate what you've tried and what you don't get.

Comment: Are you sure this is the question? This is almost word for word an exercise I give for homework, except that the probability has to be greater than $\frac12 + \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: @YehudaLindell if I'm reading the edit history correctly,  the question was originally posed with $\frac{1}{2n}$ but edited by Mark to read $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @Maeher Then the edit by Mark is incorrect. The question should be $\frac{1}{2n}$ and that's what makes the question interesting. However, we should ask if it is homework...

Comment: Someone with the same assignment, word for word, same initial typos (and then two more) just [confirmed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/199801) it has $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$, not $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking this as an exercise in understanding the meaning of mathematical statements/problems.

It's asked to exhibit a smurf (OWF, whatever that is) that wins coin throws (experiments which outcome is determined by the $=$ ) with probability at least some bound ($\Pr[\ldots] \geq \ldots$ ). It's assumed smurfs exist, known targets for the coin throws (the $x_i$ ), and we have leeway to organize the coin throws (by deciding the algorithms).

Pick any smurf, and organize how the smurf throws one-sided coins.

Comment: I like the smurf comparison. But this is also valid for a lot of assumptions underneath this entire field.