# I'm having trouble understanding this

Tags: hash, one-way-function

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)∈\{0,1\}^n$ for $n∈\mathbb N$. Prove that if one-way functions (OWFs) exist, then there exists a one-way function f such that for every bit $i∈[1, n]$ there exists an algorithm $A_i$ such that:

$$\Pr[A_i(f(x))=x_i]≥\frac12+\frac1{2n}$$

I find some information from this post [One way function existence](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/90348/one-way-function-existence?noredirect=1#comment199787_90348), but its in power

Comment: Can you tell if the actual question has $\Pr[A_i(f(x)) = x_i] \geq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$ or $\Pr[A_i(f(x)) = x_i] \geq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: Its the first one not the power one

Comment: Did my "[Pick any smurf, and organize how the smurf throws one-sided coins](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/90367/555)" analogy help enough?